# Java DecimalFormat pattern, differences between # and 0

Tags: java, design-patterns, decimalformat

I have the following code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pattern = ".00";         // a) => |.46|
//        String pattern = ".##";       // b) => |.46|
//        String pattern = ".0#";       // c) => |.46|
//        String pattern = "#.00";      // d) => |.46|
//        String pattern = "#.0#";      // e) => |.46|
//        String pattern = "#.##";      // f) => |0.46|
//        String pattern = ".#0";       // g) => IllegalArgumentException: Malformed pattern ".#0"

    double value = 0.456;
    DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
    df.applyPattern(pattern);
    String output = df.format(value);
    System.out.printf("|%s|", output);
   }  
}
```

Could someone explain that why in f) the zero before decimal point still displays while d) and e) don't even though they are all have a '#' before decimal point in the pattern? Also, what could be the reason for the exception in g) as it seems to me a valid pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case "f", the zero shows up because Java prints a `0` if it's not guaranteed that there is a fraction part to print.  The below code is taken from [JDK 17 source code for `DecimalFormat`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/text/DecimalFormat.java).  Because you have all `#` after the decimal point, `minFraDigits` is `0` so it can't assume that a fraction is present.  It apparently doesn't see that there is a fraction part to print yet.  It guards against printing nothing if the value is zero.

```
// Determine whether or not there are any printable fractional
// digits.  If we've used up the digits we know there aren't.
boolean fractionPresent = (minFraDigits > 0) ||
        (!isInteger && digitIndex < digitList.count);

// If there is no fraction present, and we haven't printed any
// integer digits, then print a zero.  Otherwise we won't print
// _any_ digits, and we won't be able to parse this string.
if (!fractionPresent && result.length() == sizeBeforeIntegerPart) {
    result.append(zero);
}
```

The case "g" format is an invalid format.  You can't have a `0`
further from the decimal point than a `#`.  It's enforced in the
parsing grammar in the [`DecimalFormat` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).  For the
Fraction part, the zeros must come first if they exist, followed by
optional `#`s.

> *Fraction*:
>          *MinimumFraction*<sub>*opt*</sub>
> *OptionalFraction*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>
> *MinimumFraction*:
>          0
> *MinimumFraction*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>
> OptionalFraction:
>         #
> *OptionalFraction*<sub>*opt*</sub>

Another part of the grammar similar to this enforces that *before* the decimal point, any `#`s must be before any `0`s, the reverse of after the decimal point.

Comment: Thanks for the g) explanation using the parsing grammar of pattern, I missed that in the javadocs. 
For the behavior in f), it seems a little bit of digging deep down in the source code of JDK could explain it. So if I understand correctly, in d) and e), because in the pattern '0' appear immediately after dp then Java knows that the fraction part can always be printed (0 if not provided) and so the leading '#' can be intepreted as 'drop the 0'. :)